# Changing player's turn

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need help in changing the player's turn.

```
    var player = 'RED';

    $(function() {

    $(whosturn(player)).draggable({
        revert: true,
        stop: {
            player = 'BLUE';
    }
    });
    });


    function whosturn(player) {
        if(player == 'RED') {
            return '.red';
        } else if(player == 'BLUE') {
            return '.blue';
        }
    }
```

Heres the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/euTwT/) to jsFiddle.

when the draggable stop, the player change its value to BLUE, so when i drag the 'Drag me blue' it wont be drag. i think the program only use the first value of the variable.
sorry for some wrong grammar. thanks in advance.

Comment: Explain clearly what you want. Explain how its working now and what you excepting it to work? If possible post some related HTML also. So others can help u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

change your code to this:

```
var player = 'RED';

function bindDrag(){

  $(whosturn(player)).draggable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function() {
        player = 'BLUE';
        bindDrag();
      }
  });
}

$(function() { 
    bindDrag();   
});

function whosturn(player) {
    if(player == 'RED') {
        return '.red';
    } else if(player == 'BLUE') {
        return '.blue';
    }
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/euTwT/3/

I hope it helps.

Comment: sir @maverickosama92 can you make it like, when you drag the red and drag it again it wont be drag unless you drag the blue one.

Comment: @reyes::: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euTwT/4/  is that what you wanted???